# <xsl:sort> not working in XSLT PI mapping

Tags: xml, xslt, sap-pi, sap-xi

I'm newbie to XSLT and I have below code which is not working for simple sort. Any help is appreciated.

```xml
<xsl:template match="ns0:MT_name">
<xsl:for-each select="name">
<xsl:sort select="name"/>
</xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
```

### input is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ns0:MT_name xmlns:ns0="http://example.com/sap/pi/TEST/xslt">
   <name>11</name>
   <name>88</name>
   <name>55</name>
</ns0:MT_name>
```

### output expected:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ns0:MT_name xmlns:ns0="http://example.com/sap/pi/TEST/xslt">
   <name>11</name>
   <name>55</name>
   <name>88</name>
</ns0:MT_name>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change `<xsl:sort select="name"/>` to `<xsl:sort select="."/>`. The current context is already `name`.

---

Try this XSLT 1.0 stylesheet:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns:ns0="http://xyz.com/sap/pi/TEST/xslt">
  <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="ns0:MT_name">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="name">
        <xsl:sort select="." order="ascending"/>
      </xsl:apply-templates>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: thanks for your answer; but that did not work: here is code: <xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:ns1="http://xyz.com/sap/pi/TEST/xslt" version="1.0"> <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/> <xsl:output method="xml"/> <xsl:template match="ns0:MT_name">` <xsl:for-each select="name"> <xsl:sort select="."/> </xsl:for-each> </xsl:template> </xsl:transform>

Comment: @premaboodi - I added a complete stylesheet.

Comment: Thanks; I got this ouput from your code: the answer is correct, but i get # after each node.. how do avoid that? <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>¶ <ns0:MT_name xmlns:ns0="http://TEST.com/sap/pi/TEST/xslt">¶ <name>11</name># <name>55</name># <name>88</name>#</ns0:MT_name>

Comment: this worked.. i was giving the namespace wrong. once i corrected it worked good. thanks.

Comment: @premaboodi - I'm glad you got it working. +1 for a good first question

Answer (score 0):

```
<xsl:sort select="." order="ascending"/>
```

**so complete template is**

```
<xsl:template match="ns0:MT_name">
  <xsl:for-each select="name">
    <xsl:sort select="." order="ascending"/>
    <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
  </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
```

I also notice in your example you have a ' mark

Comment: please igonore that mark; i have corrected it on this posting.

Comment: Hi, I get this answer for your code. sorting is correct but is there any way i can take out the name space from the output? <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>¶ <name xmlns:ns0="http://Test.com/sap/pi/TEST/xslt">11</name><name xmlns:ns0="http://Test.com/sap/pi/TEST/xslt">55</name><name xmlns:ns0= "http://Test.com/sap/pi/TEST/xslt">88</name>

Answer (score 0):

Your template doesn't create any output since the body of `xsl:for-each` consists of `xsl:sort` only. In order to generate the desired output, the stylesheet could look like this one:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
   xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
   xmlns:ns0="http://xyz.com/sap/pi/TEST/xslt">

   <xsl:template match="ns0:MT_name">
      <xsl:copy>
         <xsl:for-each select="name">
            <xsl:sort select="." data-type="number"/>
            <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
         </xsl:for-each>
      </xsl:copy>
   </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: the above code gave me this answer:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>#   11#   88#   55#

Comment: What XSLT processor do you use and how do you call it?

Comment: I don't have access to the SAP XSLT processor but anything does't work properly there. The above stylesheet definitely generates the expected XML document as given in your question.

Comment: Hi,what is best free tool to test these mappings?

Comment: There are several free processors, e.g. Saxon, Gnome's libxslt with command-line tool _xsltproc_, Xalan. They all work pretty well.

Comment: Thank you martin. I want to vote you up. i dont know how to do this. this website is new to me. thanks for your all your help.

Comment: You're welcome. Glad to hear my comments were helpful. You can vote up questions and answers by clicking on the arrow above the number (vote count) left of each posting.